# IndexError: list index out of range while using for-loop

Tags: python

While running `for` loop in  below code in python getting list index out of range error. Also, please let me know if the for loop can be written in a better way.

```
Error:- IndexError-Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-296-32d392aacb61> in <module>
---> 22         a = workbook.connections[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pandas as pd

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth('{Token_Name}',
'{Token_Secret}' , site_id="{Site}")

server = TSC.Server('Site_url',use_server_version=True)
request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)


with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):

    all_workbooks_items = list(TSC.Pager(server.workbooks, request_options))
    workbook_id=[workbook.id for workbook in all_workbooks_items]

    connection2=pd.DataFrame({"Datasource_id":connection.datasource_id,
                          "Datasource_name":a.datasource_name,
                         "Workbook Name":workbook.name} , index=[0])

    for wbk_ids in workbook_id:
        workbook = server.workbooks.get_by_id(wbk_ids)
        server.workbooks.populate_connections(workbook)
        a = workbook.connections[0]
        print({a.datasource_id,a.datasource_name,workbook.name})
        connection2=connection2.append({"Datasource_id":a.datasource_id,
                                    "Datasource_name":a.datasource_name,
                                    "Workbook Name":workbook.name} ,ignore_index=True)

    server.auth.sign_out()
```

Comment: It seems that the `workbook.connections` list is empty. That's probably something you need to check for.

Comment: Hi Kemp, The code print the data till the last line and then give away that error. And I am using the same code else where and its return data properly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
        a = workbook.connections[0]
        print({a.datasource_id,a.datasource_name,workbook.name})
        connection2=connection2.append({"Datasource_id":a.datasource_id,
                                    "Datasource_name":a.datasource_name,
                                    "Workbook Name":workbook.name} ,ignore_index=True)
```

use

```
        if workbook.connections:
            a = workbook.connections[0]
            print({a.datasource_id,a.datasource_name,workbook.name})
            connection2=connection2.append({"Datasource_id":a.datasource_id,
                                    "Datasource_name":a.datasource_name,
                                    "Workbook Name":workbook.name} ,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, it worked like a charm. And nice way to handle the error.

Comment: @You are welcome! You can mark it that it is a working answer.